# Fixing bugs in source of django packages installed through pip

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to build a small django web application. I installed the [redactor django package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wysiwyg-redactor) using pip. I found that there is a small bug which has already been fixed
    [github issue raised and fixed](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor/pull/136/commits/0ce2a3e4a564aee85c1519e72b98d3e75de68b3c)

But it has not been merged into the repo. In such cases, do I modify the sources directly in site-packages of python? How do we proceed as far as source control goes? Obviously, this does not seem to be a good practice. What is the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: Do not directly change in the third party code. Best option is to install the package from the branch which fixes this issue. Keep an eye on the original package as the PR gets merged simply change the package in your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy patched `urls.py` from https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor/pull/136/commits/0ce2a3e4a564aee85c1519e72b98d3e75de68b3c and save as `redactor_urls.py`

In Your `urls.py` instead of

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^redactor/', include('redactor.urls')),
    # ...
]
```

add

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^redactor/', include('yourapp.redactor_urls')),
    # ...
]
```